# New "We're sorry a server error occurred issue" for a web app that had previously been working

Tags: javascript

I've had an existing script running for over two years now that took data in a spreadsheet and displayed it in a filtered Dashboard Panel. I'm a teacher that has done this and become dependent on the delivery of material for my students (and for the whole school district...
This week it stopped working and there is no reason that I can see why. It is a relatively short and [straight forward script](https://script.google.com/d/1OGwCuvtj_p4Hem6eFM1DLCMzJ-KghIy2SuS0n193gu8oZHZGsIrjxc2C/edit?usp=sharing). 
Was something in here deprecated to the level that it will no longer run?

```js
// Course resource organization by @mrschwen on Twitter.
// After entering your spreadsheet key in row 6, click the Publish menu above, click Deploy as a Web App, Save a version and then share the most current link
// Note: Columns B through E on the spreadsheet must have text in them for the page to load. URL can be optional and does not have to be a video link.

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var title = app.createLabel("Algebra, Geometry and Algebra 2 Videos").setStyleAttribute('fontSize', 32);
  var data7 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1tKGafXCqlALiAbFAJyZf1lo2HWIu5bVDlR8f2jVP1pM").getDataRange().getValues();//This row is the only one you need to edit by entering the spreadsheet key between the quotation marks.
  var length = data7.length;
      var courseFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Course")
      .build();
      
   //var unitFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
      //.setFilterColumnLabel("Unit")
      //.build();
  
  var titleFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setMatchType(Charts.MatchType.ANY)
      .setFilterColumnLabel("McDougal Littell")
      .build();
      
   var descriptionFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setMatchType(Charts.MatchType.ANY)
      .setFilterColumnLabel("Description")
      .build();

      var data_7 = Charts.newDataTable();
  
  //Add Column types
data_7.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Course"); 
//data_7.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Unit");
 data_7.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Title");
  data_7.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Description");
  
  //Add rows
  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart().setDimensions(800, 1200).setInitialSortingAscending(0).enableSorting(true).setOption('allowHtml', true)
      .build();

  for(var j=1; j<length; j++){
    data_7.setValue(j, 0, data7[j][1]);
    //data_7.setValue(j, 1, data7[j][2]);
    data_7.setValue(j, 1, data7[j][3]);
    //data_7.setValue(j, 2, data7[j][2]);
    if (data7[j][5]=="")
    {data_7.setValue(j, 2, data7[j][4]);}
    else{data_7.setValue(j, 2, '<a href="'+data7[j][5]+'" target = "blank">'+data7[j][4]+'</a>');}
    
  }
  if(j==1){data_7.addRow(["No match", "",""]);}
  data_7.build();
  
  
  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(data_7)
      .bind([courseFilter,titleFilter, descriptionFilter], [tableChart])
  .build().setId("dashboard");

  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel()
                .add(app.createHorizontalPanel()
                    .add(courseFilter).add(titleFilter).add(descriptionFilter)
                    .setSpacing(20).setSize(50, 22))
                .add(app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("table")
                    .add(tableChart)
                    .setSpacing(20)));
 
  app.add(title);
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
  
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your web browser dev tool (F12 in most browsers) for errors?

Comment: I just tried that but not really sure what I'm looking for. Errors appear be a Google server-side error. I'm just a teacher that learned what I needed to for what I wanted to make.

Comment: The console will usually show code related errors.  If there are none, then I'd recommend you step through each line of your code and verify you're receiving the result you expect.  So, for example, log app to your console, like so:  `var app = UiApp.createApplication(); console.log(app);`   And then log title, etc...